# Formula field based on time-range

Tags: workflow, formula, professional-edition

am currently using Professional Edition and I have a requirement where I need to report on only Active Accounts. An active account is an account that does not have a new opportunity created in the past 6 months (created date >= 6 months).

Is there a way we can do this without using workflow? Ie. using a formula field /tasks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Create a rollup summary field on account as below
[image]
Step 2 : Create a report on account where

Opportunity Created date >= Last 6 months (Looking at the term active accounts, I believe you should check if oppty created date <= 6 months, just because your question says active accounts are the ones where oppty created date >= 6 months I have wired this report logic as below)

[image]